# Define page URL in Taza

Tags: watir

I am using [Taza](http://github.com/scudco/taza/), and I can not find a way to define page url.

I am looking at [wiki](http://github.com/scudco/taza/wiki/Pages), [rdoc](http://rdoc.info/gems/taza/0.8.7/Taza/Page) and [source](http://ttp://github.com/scudco/taza/blob/master/lib/taza/page.rb).

I have found that [WatirCraft](http://github.com/bret/watircraft/) [can do it](http://github.com/bret/watircraft/wiki/Pages), but I am not sure if it is not implemented in Taza, or if I am doing something wrong.

For:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'taza/page'

module Ecs
  class LoginPage < ::Taza::Page
    url "login"
  end
end
```

I get:

```
undefined method `url' for Ecs::LoginPage:Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charley Baker said [page URL is not implemented in Taza](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/watir-framework/message/314).